# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'generator' and 'NoneType'

Tags: python, gurobi

When trying to do a simple substraction Python gives me a typererror : TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'generator' and 'NoneType'. In my idea the 2 sides are just numbers, so I do not understand the problem really. This is my code

```
m.addConstr(sum(x[i,j,t] for i in sub_nodes[z] for j in sub_nodes[z] if j>i) <=
            sum(y[i,t] for i in sub_nodes[z]) - max([y[k,t] for k in sub_nodes[z]]) 
                                                            for z in range(len(sub_nodes))
                                                            for t in periods)
```

It is about the minus in the second line. I am using the Gurobi solver. Has anyone an idea on how to make this code work?

Comment: Of what type are `x` and `y`? Are they Gurobi variables?

Answer (score 6):

I believe your code should be `m.addConstrs` instead of `m.addConstr` (notice the **s** in "addConstr**s**").

This is because you're attempting to use a summation.

Comment: dude but it's supposed to be 1 constraint